# What is the expectation of the order of automorphism group in Erdos-Renyi random graphs?

Tags: probability, group-theory, graph-theory, random-graphs, automorphism-group

Suppose $\Gamma(V, E) \sim G(n, p)$ is an Erdos-Reyi random graph with $n$ vertices and edge probability $p$. What is the expected size of the automorphism group of $\Gamma$?

What have I tried:

Suppose, $I_{Aut(\Gamma)}$ is the indicator function of $Aut(\Gamma)$ in $Sym(V)$. Then $|Aut(\Gamma)| = \sum_{\sigma \in Sym(V)} I_{Aut(\Gamma)}(\sigma)$. Thus $$E(|Aut(\Gamma)|) = E(\sum_{\sigma \in Sym(V)} I_{Aut(\Gamma)}(\sigma)) = \sum_{\sigma \in Sym(V)} E(I_{Aut(\Gamma)}(\sigma)) = \sum_{\sigma \in Sym(V)} P(\sigma \in Aut(\Gamma))$$ However, I do not know how to proceed further.

Here is also the analysis of the situation for small $n$:

If $n = 1$, then $E(|Aut(\Gamma)|) = 1$ because $|Aut(\Gamma)| = 1$ almost surely.

If $n = 2$, then $E(|Aut(\Gamma)|) = 2$ because $|Aut(\Gamma)| = 2$ almost surely.

If $n = 3$, then $|Aut(\Gamma)| = 6$ with probability $p^3 + (1 - p)^3$ and $|Aut(\Gamma)| = 2$ with probability with probability $1 - (p^3 + (1 - p)^3)$. Thus $E(|Aut(\Gamma)|) = 2 + 4(p^3 + (1 - p)^3)$.

Also note, that because the automorphism group of a graph is always isomorphic to the automorphism group of its complement graph, that value is invariant under the map $p \mapsto (1-p)$

Comment: Did you try Google? I quickly found a few papers from the 80s which suggested that random graphs have trivial automorphism groups. ("Suggested" as they either had assumptions or proved that $|\operatorname{Aut}(\Gamma)|$ is very small.) I guess a more dedicated Google will uncover the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a theorem that the proportion of isomorphism classes of graphs on $n$ vertices with with a non-identity automorphism goes to zero as $n$ increases.
It’s quite standard; one proof can be found in "Algebraic Graph Theory"
by me and Royle.